# How to outline text with html5/css3?

Tags: html, outline, stroke, css

I'm trying to use shadow to outline text -- a solution I got from other stackoverflow threads.  Currently, text-outline and text-stroke are barely supported.

I'm getting a strange behavior on one of the letters.

To use the shadow hack I did:

```
<div id="background">
 <h1 id="buzz-joy">BU<span id="small-raised-z">Z</span>Z-JOY</h1>
</div>
```

and

```
#background {
    height 100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
}
#buzz-joy {
    font-family:"Arial Black";
    color: Yellow;
    font-size:4em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 black, 2px -2px 0 black, -2px 2px 0 black, -2px -2px 0 black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

to get

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/e3QUp

But I get a strange behavior on the "Y".

Any suggestions for how to fix that problem?

Comment: You should probably mention what browser your "strange behavior" is occurring with and, for that matter, exactly what the strange behavior is. On Firefox it looks fine to me.

Comment: same for Chrome on Mac, looking just fine

Comment: If you're okay with using mixins, here's a solution that works great: http://codepen.io/pixelass/pen/gbGZYL

Answer (score 2):

The trick works by setting 4 shadows, going to the 4 diagonal directions.

This works ok for straight edges and square corners, but doesn't for the upper braces of the Y, that are in a *bad* angle.

The only way that I can think of to fix that is to increase the number of shadows, pointing in as many angles as needed until you are satified with the result.

The shadows that you have are aprox 3 px long (square root of 2+2 + 2*2), so you can go with other values in the style 3*cos(a) 3*sin(a)

Comment: I'll give it a try.  I love that you used math!